# Ubuntu 16.04 not going to suspend mode when laptop lid is closed

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management, laptop

When I **manually** suspend and close the lid then it works. But when only the lid is closed it does not goes to suspend mode. As a result laptop gets hot over time. Although I have **suspend** option selected when lid is closed.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any connected referrals to the computer such as USB keyboard?

Comment: No. I have no usb devices connected